# PHP PDO Will transaction rollback when execute fails?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, execute

Example code:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {   
    $query1 = $pdo->prepare(...);
    $query2 = $pdo->prepare(...);

    $query1->execute();
    $query2->execute();

    $pdo->commit();
} catch(Exception $e){
    try {
        $pdo->rollBack();
    } catch(Exception $re){
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

I know that prepare can throw exception, and commit will throw exception if there is no transaction running.

But is it possible to occur such situation in which prepare will success but execute fails? It would not cause rollback? Does commit also throws when execution failed (I don't think so, as documentation says it throws only when there is no transaction).

So should I explicitly check for execution result and throw my own exceptions to cause rollback like this?:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {

    $query1 = $pdo->prepare(...);
    $query2 = $pdo->prepare(...);

    if(!$query1->execute()){
        throw new Exception('Query1 failed to execute.');
    }

    if(!$query2->execute()){
        throw new Exception('Query2 failed to execute.');
    }

    $pdo->commit();
} catch(Exception $e){
    try {
        $pdo->rollBack();
    } catch(Exception $re){
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Do you have PDO configured to Throw Exceptions on Error

Comment: But basically if you dont get to a Commit the transaction should be rolled back

Comment: PDO::rollBack() throws a `PDOException` when it comes to rollback without a previous opened transaction.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do have it configured this way. But if prepare doesn't throw and execute will fail then I will get to commit with failed execute.

Comment: @Zeratops That's true but It is not relevant to me right now. I would like to know if I should check for errors when calling execute or something else will fail on execute fail and commit won't occur, or even commit itself will fail if there was any execute that failed.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind, in order to emulate a failure for one of your execute, would be a violation of some foreign key constraint. Whatever, I do not know if, with @RiggsFolly suggestion, PDO will throw an exception instead of false if your execute statement fails. You will probably need to check this.

Comment: _But if prepare doesn't throw and execute will fail then I will get to commit with failed execute_ No, if the execute fails it will throw an Exception and go to your rollback

Comment: And if the RollBack fails, there is nothing you can do to recover from that so why have that in a `try/catch`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly If rollback would fail I could log it.

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that basically you're asking, does execute() throw an exception, if it fails?

Yes, it does.

Therefore your code will be rolled back automatically. No need for checking manually. You can test it with a duplicate unique key error for example.

Comment: Is there anything about it in the documentation?

Comment: Yes. The documentation says that PDO throws exceptions on errors if configured so. I would rather ask where did you get that it's only prepare that is throwing exceptions.

Comment: It is because documentation says explicitly that prepare returns false, and only if pdo is configured so, it will throw exception. In case of execute it only says it will return false, and there is nothing about throwing exceptions, so I would say that documentation is not consequent (?).

Comment: Well, yes, it looks like so.

Comment: @Mr_KoKa Of course you could always set up a test where the execute fails and see what happens